# How to validate "ToggleButton" in flutter?

Tags: flutter, validation, if-statement, togglebutton

As It seems there is no built-in `validatior()` for `ToggleButton` I tried to do something like following inside an `ElevatedButton()`:

```
          onPressed: () {
            print('this is _selectedOptions: $_selectedOptions');
            if (_selectedOptions == [false, false, false]) {
              const SnackBar(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                content:
                    Text('You should select at least 1 option '),
              );
            } 
          }
```

And I see `this is _selectedOptions:  [false, false, false]`  prints out, but it doesn't go into the if statement I don't know why?

Please let me know why it doesn't go into the `if` statement, also if there is a better way of validating `ToggleButton` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change if statement.

From

```dart
if (_selectedOptions == [false, false, false])
```

To

```dart
if (!_selectedOptions.contains(true))
```

It's because of Dart's characteristic, check below.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/operator_equals.html

**"the equality comparison does not compare the elements of the two lists."**

Comment: Do you know what is wrong with the SnackBar? It doesn't show up.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars You should command snackBar to show. const snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
); ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);